# How to add header in Rest aussured pf RestTemplate

Tags: automated-tests, resttemplate, rest-assured, web-api-testing

I have been trying to automate some API Testing using either resttemplate or Restassured library but im facing issues on post request. I cant seems to figure how to handle this. I keep getting 415 unsupported type error , I tried many ideas already and read hundreds of threads. Please if someone have a solution let me know. 
This is the developer code

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postData(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream is,
                         @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileName,
                         @FormDataParam("checkInCommInfoInput") String checkInCommInfoInput,
                         @HeaderParam("authorization") String authString) { }
```

This is what I tried with resttemplate
String addURI = "https://myURI";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

```
    //headers.add("Accept","*/*");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Authorization", " a values will be here ");



     System.out.println("**************************"+headers.getContentType());

    String jsonBody = "my json file will be here";
    //System.out.println("\n\n" + jsonBody);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonBody, headers);

    //POST Method to Add New Employee
    response = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(addURI, entity, String.class);
    responseBodyPOST = response.getBody();
    // Write response to file
    responseBody = response.getBody().toString();
```

What I tried with RestAssured

```
        RestAssured.useRelaxedHTTPSValidation();
    RestAssured.baseURI ="https://myURI";

    EncoderConfig encoderconfig = new EncoderConfig();
     Response response = RestAssured.given()

                .header("Content-Type","application/json" )

                .header("Authorization", "a vvalues will be here")
                .header("Accept",ContentType.JSON )
               .config(RestAssured.config()
                       .encoderConfig(encoderconfig.appendDefaultContentCharsetToContentTypeIfUndefined(false)))
                //.contentType(ContentType.JSON)

               // .accept("application/json")
                .log().all().body(jsonBody).post()
                .then()
                   .assertThat()
                   .log().ifError()
                   .statusCode(200)
                   .extract().response();

     System.out.println("-------------"+ response.getBody().asString());
```

Answer (score 0):

API under test `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` but the test sends content with `.header("Content-Type","application/json" )`

415 error as you have clearly mentioned `unsupported type error` there is a content type mismatch between what the body content that the test client sends and what the API accepts.

See this blogpost: https://blog.jayway.com/2011/09/15/multipart-form-data-file-uploading-made-simple-with-rest-assured/ on how to do send MULTIPART_FORM_DATA